# How to resize view width and height dynamically?

Tags: android

I am adding two views to a linearlayout. When I click on the first view it has to occupy second views width also. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This code sets the width and height of yourView that was placed inside a RelativeLayout.

```
int viewWidth = 69;
int viewHeight = 69;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(viewWidth, viewHeight);

View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.yourView);
v.setLayoutParams(newViewParams);
```

Alternatively, for a LinearLayout, you need to use this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams newViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(viewWidth, viewHeight);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just set second view's visibility to View.GONE in View1 onClickListener? That's simpler and faster than adjusting first view's width